# Compare efficiency of two different LINQ statements

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning C# (background in C++), and I have a question about LINQ expressions. The following two functions both do the same thing (near as I can tell). The type of Wombats is `System.Data.Linq.Table<Wombat>`.

I'm interested to know

1. Which is more efficient?
2. Does it even matter?
3. Is there something to be gained by returning IQueryqble, instead?
4. Is there some etiquette here that prefers one of the three?

My guess is that the second is more efficient, but that it doesn't really matter unless there are millions of wombats in the wombat table. And returning an IQueryable doesn't seem to matter much since we're only ever returning a single wombat.

Thanks in advance!

```
    public static DBConnector.Connections.Wombat getWombat(String wombatID)
    {
        var db = getDBInstance();
        return db.Wombats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.ToString() == wombatID);
    }

    public static DBConnector.Connections.Wombat getWombat(String wombatID)
    {
        var db = getDBInstance();
        var guid = new System.Guid(wombatID);
        return db.Wombats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == guid);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `== guid` in your second example

Comment: At this point you should be rather ask about the efficiency of `LinQ to SQL`, which seems to be what you're using.

Comment: @lc. I do---I was editing variable names and must have missed this.

Comment: @HighCore: I'm not really concerned about optimizing the thing, per se, I just want to confirm my intuition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will depend completely on the DB's LINQ provider, and how it turns this into SQL.  You could [profile the resulting SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) (or even just [inspecting the SQL trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143042/65358)) and determine which is more efficient.

I suspect that most providers will do better with the second option, as the actual check will be the same type - the query on the server will not need to convert each row to a string, and compare via a string comparison.  This will likely allow the indexing to work properly, and make it far more efficient.  That being said, a clever provider could do this conversion for you, in which case the two options may be identical.

Answer (score 5):

Your guess is right, the second query is likely to be more efficient, because it would parse a GUID once rather than converting a GUID in each row to a string. The query provider may optimize this, but it does not have to; it is also possible that your query provider would choose to convert GUIDs to strings for comparison, but that would be a rather unfortunate choice.

You are also correct in assuming that it would not matter unless there is a significant number of `Wombat` objects in the table.

There is one significant difference going in favor of the second query: the `ToString` method may not be recognized by the query provider, so your first query would not even execute due to a run-time error.

Comment: It depends on what the query provider does. Bear in mind that this is an `IQueryable<T>` - it's not like the code *as written* is going to get executed.

Answer (score 3):

1. Look at the generated sql for each case.
2. Examine the execution time, query plan, and IO of each query in sql studio.
3. ???
4. Profit.

Answer (score 1):

If you return IQuerable you could delay evaulation allowing someone else to update the value first.

Comment: Ahh good point. I don't think I have to worry about this here, but definitely something to keep in mind in the future.